# Laravel authorization policy not being called

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

My authorization policy is not being called and I am receiving a 403 error. This is part of an API.

I have tried calling it from the controller by using the 'authorize' helper or via middleware. I have also tried using the auth()->guard('api')->user()->can().

**DeckPolicy.php**

```php
public function view(User $user, Deck $deck)
{
    dd('policy called');

    if ($deck->private) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

**AuthServiceProvider.php**

```php
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $policies = [
        'App\Deck' => 'App\Policies\DeckPolicy'
    ];

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
    }
}
```

**DecksController.php**

```php
public function show(Deck $deck)
{
    $this->authorize('view', $deck);

    return new DeckResource($deck);
}
```

I expect the output to be 'policy called', but all I am receiving is a 403 error page when using Postman.

I would like to understand why the 'authorize()' helper function is not working as expected.

Comment: Check what all happens before the gate that might be affecting authorization. Is there any other middleware running on that route? Are there other classes or vendor packages that interact with permissions? What happens if you disable authentication (not authorization) and visit the url in the browser?

Comment: I am using no other middleware. It does work when using auth('api')->user()->can('view', $deck) with postman, but with angular API call it returns CORS error.